# android pdf viewer stackoverflow error while reading password protected file

Tags: android, pdf, passwords, pdfviewer

i am able to read normal pdf file which does not have any password properly using pdfviewer.jar, however when i try to read password protected file i get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

can any one tell me what is wrong ?

following is the code

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPdfViewerActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME,"mnt/sdcard/sample.pdf");        
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you please also check the password length for this? I have faced similar issue when password generated was above 20 characters.

Comment: yes , the password length is 11 characters

Comment: my problem is exactly like this https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/issues/8 , i did the changes of cipher.init but it is not working for me

Comment: Did you tried by manually opening the encrypted PDF file using the password generated by your app?

Comment: yes i tried to open it with polaris it prompts for password and on entering password it opens PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution mentioned on github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/issues/8 worked for me , i was doing changes in src folder of PDF viewer but my app was still referencing jar (which did not have that changes)